# MS Dynamics365 - generate custom serial number, ensure uniqueness

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, unique-constraint, dynamics-365

I am developing a Dynamics365 CRM based solution, and for a custom entity we've defined, we need to create custom serial numbers.

For various business reasons, neither a GUID nor a sequential numbering scheme will do - business insists on a format of

```
99-9999-9999
```

where each group of numbers is basically a random group of numbers.

Creating those in a plugin is easy - but how do I ensure **uniqueness**?? I'm a C#/SQL Server developer at heart, and in SQL Server / T-SQL, I'd just create an unique index on my "Entity" table on this column. Checking if a newly created number exists would be easy-peasy - just do an

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.MyEntity WHERE SerialNum = @SerialNumGenerated)
```

check, and since that single column is indexed and `NOT NULL`, it would be quite fast, too.

But **how** do I do the same (at least as "same" as possible) in Dynamics365? How can I programmatically check (inside my C# plugin) if a newly created "serial number" has not yet been used - and do so it's quick enough not to slow down the save process too much? Can I somehow also "index" that property on my custom entity and do something similar to the `IF EXISTS()` check in T-SQL ?

Thanks for any hints or pointers!

Comment: hmmm it's can still be sequential numbering ... 1 => 00-0000-0001,  2=>00-0000-0002 ....

Comment: @Selvin: **no** - no sequential numbering - it's explicitly **required** to be groups of random numbers

Comment: you might find [this article](https://www.akaes.com/blog/how-to-implement-robust-auto-numbering-using-transactions-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm/) interesting.

Comment: @Aron: thanks - but that's again just plain old sequence number generation - that's not what I'm looking for

Comment: On a related note, although I haven't done it in a while, Microsoft Support should be able to create a [custom index](https://crmtipoftheday.com/39/custom-indexes-in-crm-online/) on the serial # column for you. You might also want to look into whether [alternate keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/define-alternate-keys-entity) automatically get an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do this numbering within a pre-operation plugin. This is the only way to completely guarentee uniqueness, it is quite performant, and the number will immediately exist upon creation of the record.

1) Generate the characters
You can use whatever method you want, as a database developer I usually just default to what I am familiar with, a substring of Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

2) Check uniqueness

```
    QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("[prefix_yourentityname]")
    query.Criteria.AddCondition("prefix_yourfieldname", ConditionOperator.Equal, [IDNumber]);
    query.TopCount = 1;
    bool isUnique = Service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities.Count = 0;
```

3) Set the ID number on the target so that it is saved with the transaction

**Performance:** 
This check obviously results in a small read operation against the database but you don't have a better option. If you are using on-premise CRM you can add an index against this table including the ID field. Indexing the CRM database is supported by Microsoft.

If you are using CRM online, the only thing you can do is add your ID field to the Quick Find View "View Columns" and "Search Columns" for this entity. The CRM application generates an index on each table based on the configuration within the Quick Find view, so adding your ID column to this view will result in that field being added to the index.

Comment: Yes, that's basically my broad thinking. The point I'm a bit uncertain about is how to make the check to see if the generated new key is unique fast enough so it won't harm performance too much. In SQL Server, I'd optimize by using a `IF EXISTS()` clause, rather than a `COUNT(*) > 0` to be more efficient - can I do something similar here in Dynamics, too?

Comment: I believe using the TopCount property might essentially make your query work like IF EXISTS(). The performance benefit of EXISTS over COUNT(*) > 0 is that EXISTS will exit once it finds a single record, and I believe the same is true if you set TopCount = 1. Updated my code above.

Comment: I also added some information regarding table indexing.

Comment: How does a pre-operation plugin guarentee uniqueness?

Comment: Pre-operation plugins execute synchronously before the record is created. If during this transaction you check and verify that the generated number doesn't already exist, then you will never create a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are unable to design a generation formula that is astronomically unlikely to generate duplicates (e.g. a GUID). You will need to follow this general logic.

1. Run formula to create a unique id.
2. Search CRM via `RetrieveMultiple` to check for any records with that number already.
3. If number already exists; go back to 1.
4. Else; update record with new id.

You then have to decide where to execute your code. Two options spring to mind.

1. In the 'box', e.g. a plugin or JavaScript. In this case you would have the issue that its possible to have multiple executions of your formula concurrently with no knowledge of each other. Depending on how likely your formula is to generate duplicates and the rate that records are created this may be acceptable.
2. Go out of the 'box', e.g. a console application running on a schedule that finds records without numbers. It then numbers each record one by one. A single threaded approached has the benefit of ensuring uniqueness, but is going to be slower from a user perspective.

If it was me and I had to implement this requirement, I would go for option 2.

Comment: Yes, that's basically my broad thinking - the point I'm a bit uncertain about is how to make the check to see if the generated new key is unique fast enough so it won't bog down the system. Is there anything I can do from the Dynamics point of view to make that check via "RetrieveMultiple" be really fast in this situation? Like e.g. creating an index on the attribute of the entity, or something along those lines?

Comment: @marc_s It will probably be fast enough, but; on premise you can add your own [indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/supported-extensions#unsupported-customizations), online in theory Microsoft create the indexes [automagically](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/218784/adding-index-for-lookup-search-performance-ms-dynamics-crm-online). Beyond that you could look at some sort of architecture where you generate all the ids upfront and place them into a queue which you pop off so you dont have to check.